# Mongo Custom Configuration Is not connecting to Mongo instance

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have an application that talk to multiple mongo instances and DBs. I create each  MongoTemplate to connect to separate DB

Here is my properties

```
my.dburi=mongodb://user_name:password@mongo-instance01,mongo-instance02,mongo-instance03/database_appname?authSource=admin&replicaSet=mongoappinstance&ssl=false&w=majority&readPreference=primaryPreferred
my.dbname=database_appname
```

Here it Configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class MyMongoConfigs extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

  protected static final Logger logger_c = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyMongoConfigs.class);

  @Value("${my.dburi}")
  private String host;

   @Value("${my.dbname}")
  private String dbName;

  @Override
  protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return dbName;
  }

  @Override
  public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    return   new MongoClient(host);
  }

  @Bean
  public MongoTemplate myMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    MongoTemplate myTemp = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
    return myTemp;
  }



  @Bean
  public MongoCustomConversions customConversions(){
    return createCustomConversions();
  }

  @Bean
  public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() throws Exception{
    DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory());
    MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, mongoMappingContext());
    converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
    // This line removes the _class field from all Spring Mongo records
    converter.setTypeMapper( new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null) );
    return converter;
  }


}
```

But I'm getting socket Exception

> com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb:......
>
> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException:

At same-time when I try with spring-boot default configuration it works fine

used default spring data property

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user_name:password@mongo-instance01,mongo-instance02,mongo-instance03/database_appname?authSource=admin&replicaSet=mongoappinstance&ssl=false&w=majority&readPreference=primaryPreferred
```

Here is the log

```
019-09-16 09:11:41.162  INFO 39908 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-09-16 09:11:42.466  INFO 39908 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[mongo-instance01:27017, mongo-instance02:27017, mongo-instance03:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500, requiredReplicaSetName='mongoappinstance'}
2019-09-16 09:11:42.467  INFO 39908 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server mongo-instance02:27017 to client view of cluster
2019-09-16 09:11:42.495  INFO 39908 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server mongo-instance02:27017 to client view of cluster
2019-09-16 09:11:42.497  INFO 39908 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server mongo-instance02:27017 to client view of cluster
2019-09-16 09:11:42.622  INFO 39908 --- [line02:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:4897703}] to mongo-instance02:27017
2019-09-16 09:11:42.632  INFO 39908 --- [line01:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:4393722}] to mongo-instance01:27017
2019-09-16 09:11:42.632  INFO 39908 --- [line03:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:4915793}] to mongo-instance03:27017
2019-09-16 09:11:42.641  INFO 39908 --- [line02:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongo-instance02:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 16]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=null, roundTripTimeNanos=17769877, setName='mongoappinstance', canonicalAddress=mongo-instance02:27017, hosts=[mongo-instance01:27017, mongo-instance03:27017, mongo-instance02:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='mongo-instance03:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=3, lastWriteDate=Mon Sep 16 09:08:18 BST 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=2416622912401383}
2019-09-16 09:11:42.656  INFO 39908 --- [line01:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongo-instance01:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 16]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=null, roundTripTimeNanos=23522766, setName='mongoappinstance', canonicalAddress=mongo-instance01:27017, hosts=[mongo-instance01:27017, mongo-instance03:27017, mongo-instance02:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='mongo-instance03:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=3, lastWriteDate=Mon Sep 16 09:08:18 BST 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=2416622927444543}
2019-09-16 09:11:42.656  INFO 39908 --- [line03:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongo-instance03:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 16]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=null, roundTripTimeNanos=23504988, setName='mongoappinstance', canonicalAddress=mongo-instance03:27017, hosts=[mongo-instance01:27017, mongo-instance03:27017, mongo-instance02:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='mongo-instance03:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=5ca1d2f4d7f06c38b0ee8b03, setVersion=3, lastWriteDate=Mon Sep 16 09:08:18 BST 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=2416622927444543}
2019-09-16 09:11:42.657  INFO 39908 --- [line03:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Setting max election id to 5ca1d2f4d7f06c38b0ee8b03 from replica set primary mongo-instance03:27017
2019-09-16 09:11:42.657  INFO 39908 --- [line03:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Setting max set version to 3 from replica set primary mongo-instance03:27017
2019-09-16 09:11:42.657  INFO 39908 --- [line03:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered replica set primary mongo-instance03:27017
```

Can some one please guide me what I'm doing wrong in my custom configuration ??

Comment: I think you need to getMongoClientURI and pass to MongoClient, add this in mongoClient() method,  `MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(host);` `return new MongoClient(uri);` let me know if this works

Comment: are you using any different mongoDB connector?

Comment: @dkb pardo me i didn't get you question  , if you mean i'm trying to used different db connector for different DBs ? yes

Comment: my bad @edwin, I mean are you using `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-*` * -> sync/legacy/async

Comment: if yes, Ref: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/

Comment: @dkb thanks for the tip , but since i'm using sping data which internally uses 'mongo-java-driver' i can see in logs it using 3.8.2 version . meanwhile adding MongoClientURI fixed the issue for me. if you can put it as answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update `mongoClient()` method to following,
you need to wrap connection string to `MongoClientURI` and pass `MongoClientURI` to `MongoClient`.

```
@Override
  public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(host);
    return new MongoClient(uri);
  }
```

Ref: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/